# What's the difference between #define AVOIDANCE_DELAY 1 and delay(1)

Tags: arduino

I saw this

```
#define AVOIDANCE_DELAY 1
```

in one project.
What's the difference to `delay(1)`?

Answer (score 0):

`#define AVOIDANCE_DELAY 1` defines a macro.

The preprocessor will replace any occurance of `AVOIDANCE_DELAY` in your code with `1` when you compile your code.

https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/structure/further-syntax/define/

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/replace#.23define_directives

`delay(1);` is a function call. It calls the function `delay` with parameter `1`.

https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/time/delay/

Comment: `delay` requires a compile-time constant value, so they are equivalent from an assembled-code standpoint.  As a matter of opinion, I would prefer the macro because it's easily replaceable if used in more than one place, and is self-documenting.